# Limit the length of a line

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing, p5.js

I'm trying to draw a line that represents a 'slingshot' and I want it to have a maximum draw length.

in p5 I'm drawing a line between positionA and positionB:

```
line(posA.x, posA.y, posB.x, posB.y);
```

posA is the mouse x and y.  posB is the position of a circle on the canvas.

What I want to do is limit the length of the line, so that it is never more than 40px long, but still points toward the mouse from the circle.

Comment: You will need to calculate the distance between the two points. If it is too long, then you need to find the angle of the vector between points A and B then find the point which is 40px along that angle from point B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between 2 points is calculated by `sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)`.
If you divide the vector of one point to the other by its length then you get the [Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) with length 1.

Calculate the unit vector from `posA` to `posB` and multiply it by 40:

```js
// (dx, dy): vector form "posA" to "posB" 
let dx = posB.x-posA.x;
let dy = posB.y-posA.y;

// dist : euclidean distance, length of the vecotr 
let dist = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

// (ux, uy): unit vector form 'posA' in direction to 'posB', with length 1 
let ux = dx / dist;
let uy = dy / dist;

// (x2, y2): point with a distance of 40 from "posA" an the vector to "posB"
let x2 = posA.x + ux * 40;
let y2 = posA.y + uy * 40;

line(posA.x, posA.y, x2, y2);
```

---

In p5.js you can use [`p5.Vector`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector) for all this calculations.

- [`.sub()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/sub) subtracts two points and calculates the vector
- [`.normalize()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/normalize) computes the unit vector with length 1
- [`.mult()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/mult) scales the vector
- [`.add()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/add) adds the vectors to the point

```js
let A = createVector(posA.x, posA.y);
let B = createVector(posB.x, posB.y);

let P = B.sub(A).normalize().mult(40).add(A);
line(posA.x, posA.y, P.x, P.y);
```

See the example:

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(200, 200);
}

function draw() {

    background(0, 0, 0);
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    strokeWeight(5);

    let A = createVector(width/2, height/2);
    let B = createVector(mouseX, mouseY);

    let P = B.sub(A).normalize().mult(40).add(A);
    line(A.x, A.y, P.x, P.y);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is awesome, I especially like that it includes the math and the p5 way.  

I haven't tried the first part yet, but the p5 line drawing is acting odd.  I'm logging the positions of A and B which are A: 241 348, B: 249 360.  But the line is drawing from my mouse to somewhere in the top left corner, sometimes off screen.

Comment: Mouse is posA, circle is posB

Comment: @Ashbury So you've to calculate `A.sub(B).normalize().mult(40)`

Comment: sorry I'm still getting the same results swapping A.sub(B)

Here are the values:
A: x: 375 y: 216
B: x: 249 y: 360
P: x: -26 y: 30

Comment: @Ashbury Sorry, I've forgotten to add the vector to A. I've corrected the answer.  I did it in the explanation part, but I didn't in the p5.Vector (2nd) part