# How to make an object rotate in the direction of my mouse cursor?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I have a square (`{x,y,width,height}`) and I'd like to rotate it by some angle to look at my cursor (which is `cursorX, cursorY` in p5.js)

how can I calculate the angle needed to make my square point in the direction of my cursor?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/conorbuck/2606166

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to find the direction of the mouse position ([`mouseX`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseX)/[`mouseY`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseY)) to the object (`posX`/`posY`) in the following example).
The vector of the position to the mouse cursor can be calculated by subtracting the 2 points (`posX-mouseY`, `posY-mouseY`). The angle of an vector can be calculated by `Math.atan2(y, x)`:

```js
let angle = Math.atan2(mouseY-posY, mouseX-posX);
```

Use [`rotate()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/rotate) to rotate the object.

```js
rotate(angle)
```

Note in this case the top of the object is orientated to the mouse. If e.g. the right of the object has to be orientated to the mouse, then you've to add an offset angle:

```js
 rotate(angle + radians(-90))
```

The answer to [Limit the length of a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56485395/limit-the-length-of-a-line) may also be of interest.

Example:

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 200);
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    
    let posX = width/2;
    let posY = height/2;
    
    let angle = Math.atan2(mouseY-posY, mouseX-posX);

    translate(posX, posY);
    rotate(angle)
    //rotate(angle + radians(-90))

    stroke(255, 255, 0)
    fill(255, 0, 0)
    beginShape();
    vertex(-3, -3);
    vertex(50, -3);
    vertex(50, -6);
    vertex(60, 0);
    vertex(50, 6);
    vertex(50, 3);
    vertex(-3, 3);
    vertex(-3, -3);
    endShape()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```